# Multiple domain names for the same apache server

Tags: php, apache, web, dns

I'm working on a little project where an apache server with php running on it runs several different websites on it. I want to give these sites domains.

Can I put my ip followed by and identifying number ex: `192.16.0.1/?sumNum` into the DNS to differentiate between witch website is being asked for? They all have the same `index.php` homepage file.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  Can you give more examples of expected behaviour and what you've tried so far?

Comment: Apache supports name based virtual hosts, which allows you to associate domain names with different document roots and environments.  A Http 1.1. request includes the domain in the request, from which the server can do the association.

Comment: this is off-topic here

Comment: Thanks Progrock name based virtual hosts is what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I put my IP followed by and identifying number ex:
>   192.16.0.1/?sumNum into the DNS to differentiate between which website is being asked for?

No, what you are talking about is called [Named based Virtual Hosting in Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html). As it says in the Apache documentation:

> With name-based virtual hosting, the server relies on the client to
>   report the hostname as part of the HTTP headers. Using this technique,
>   many different hosts can share the same IP address.

You start by registering your domains in the DNS with a registrar, such as Google Domains.  Then, through the registrar, you will create a DNS A record, for each domain pointing to the same IP address.

Within Apache, when you set up the named based virtual hosting, you are effectively saying, when you see this domain name, go to this particular directory on this computer to serve up the files (which are your HTML/PHP files). But in your case, you can point each of those virtual hosts to the same directory.

You can then use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` within PHP to retrieve the domain coming in and do what you want to do differently for each domain.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for pointing me in the right direction I really appreciate it.